# Time of retrieving entities from datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have an App Engine application which uses Datastore. One of kinds in Datastore contains 
over 2,000,000 entities. Queries on that kind are extremely slow.
For example query which returns about 50 entities takes 3 - 5 seconds. I don't know if number of filters matter  but in that case I set 7 filters on query.
Queries on other kinds are also slow in my opinion. For instance query returning about 20 
entities from kind which contains over 90 000 entities takes about 1 second.

I build composite indexes for that queries but it doesn't help too much. Changing chunk 
size and using keys only queries doesn't help as well.

What has the biggest influence to time of executing queries to Datastore?
Is there any way to speed up my queries?

The way that I retrieve entities is similiar with an example that I found in documentation:

```
Query q = new Query("Person").setFilter(heightRangeFilter);

    PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);

    for (Entity result : pq.asIterable()) {

      String firstName = result.getProperty("firstName").toString();
      String lastName = result.getProperty("lastName").toString();
      Long height = (Long) result.getProperty("height");

    }
```

Total size of that entities is 423.33 MB, build-in indexes: 2.87GB, composite indexes: 1.85GB

I am using Logger class to log diagnostic informations. Time difference between two logs I can see in admin console.
When I put log in the first and the last line of loop that iterates through entities I can see strange pauses between iterations. I have no idea what is reason of it.

Example:
   15:06:30.565 Start
   15:06:30.566 Stop
   15:06:30.566 Start
   15:06:30.566 Stop
   15:06:30.572 Start
   15:06:30.572 Stop
   15:06:30.583 Start
   15:06:30.583 Stop
   15:06:30.595 Start
   15:06:30.595 Stop
   15:06:30.595 Start
   15:06:30.595 Stop
   15:06:30.595 Start
   15:06:30.596 Stop
   15:06:30.658 Start
   15:06:30.658 Stop
   15:06:30.659 Start
   15:06:30.659 Stop
   15:06:30.666 Start
   15:06:30.666 Stop
   ...

EDIT:
I modified my query to use 6 filters and build new composite index for it. It seems to be faster but it runs still over 2 seconds when retrieving about 100 entities.
The way that I create filters is similar to example from documentation:

```
Filter timeMinFilter =
  new FilterPredicate("time",
                      FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL,
                      startTime);

Filter timeMaxFilter =
  new FilterPredicate("time",
                      FilterOperator.LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL,
                      stopTime);

Filter heightRangeFilter = CompositeFilterOperator.and(timeMinFilter, timeMaxFilter);
```

Does it matter that I set FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL and FilterOperator.LESS_THAN on a string property?

Thanks for help.

Comment: How are you timing how long the query takes? Maybe there is overhead in the code that makes the datastore call?

Comment: It's better to use `(String) result.getProperty("firstName")`. `toString()` method is a "best-effort" to represent any type as a String, while in this case you need to simply cast the type. For example, if you pass the wrong type to the "firstName" property, you will get an exception (i.e. you will find out that there is a problem) if you try to cast it, but `toString()` will work even when the type makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

The query speed on App Engine does not depend on the number of entities stored in the Datastore. It depends only on the number and size of entities that you retrieve from your query.

The query times that you have indicate that there is a problem in a way that you retrieve these entities. It can be a problem in code used to run queries, or it can be a problem with the way entities have been created. There is no way to dig deeper with the information that you have provided in your question.

UPDATE:

Try to use this code instead, and see if you see an improvement:

```
for (Entity result : pq.asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults().chunkSize(100).prefetchSize(100)) {
```

You should use this line every time when you expect more than 10 results in your query. Note that the number can be anywhere between 0 and 1000, so you may try different limits for different queries to see what works best.

Comment: Just pointing out another possibility into his error : If he has no custom index for this query and uses the zigzag algorithm with 7 different indexes, it could definitely slow down the query

Comment: You are totally right. Lukasz does mention "composite indexes" in his question, however. Also, we don't know which run-time and Datastore libraries he is using. Some of them throw an exception if you create a query which does not have a supporting index.

Comment: I am using Java Runtime Environment and DatastoreService to run my queries.

Comment: How do you create a filter?